# Confirmation of SQL query

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to run a query in my database to remove products that were added before a certain time. So far i have this:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND date < '2015-09-24 11:00:00'
```

I just wanted some opinions of whether or not this is correct before i run it.

Comment: Before running any DELETE queries you do not understand, run them first as SELECT queries, and then confirm that you understand the results.

Comment: Yes, i agree with @xxfelixxx before execute DELETE query first execute smae with SELECT and check whether the data is coming right or not then use DELETE query. But i suggest before doing DELETE first take a backup of that table.

Comment: Will do :) Thank you. Will post here if successful, for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert first the column [date] and the value. Why ? , to avoid unexpected result or error due to formatting issues.

something like this:

```
    DELETE FROM wp_posts 
    WHERE post_type = 'product' 
    AND CONVERT(DATETIME, [date]) < CONVERT(DATETIME,'2015-09-24 11:00:00')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will do :) Thank you. Will post here if successful, for reference.

Comment: Glad that i help you, kindly mark as answer if this resolve your question. :)

Comment: When using:
`SELECT * 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'product' 
AND CONVERT(DATETIME, [date]) < CONVERT(DATETIME,'2015-09-24 11:00:00')`
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[date]) < CONVERT(DATETIME,'2015-09-24 11:00:00') ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`post_pare' at line 4

Comment: @ChristopherShewLouw oh i saw awhile ago that sql server is tagged, in that case , that will give an error.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the results using

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'product' AND `post_modified` < '2015-09-24 11:00:00'
```

Then made sure it is what i needed to delete and ran the DELETE version of this query.

Thanks you for all the assistance :)